# Does Istanbul airport have x-ray scanners before the exit?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, airport-security, photography, isl, x-ray-machines

I always travel with (photographic) film and I'd like to know how many X-Ray stops I'm likely to encounter on a given trip.

Most of the time, I have my carry-on scanned once at security here in Canada before leaving, and maybe another time if I have a layover. Sometimes though (Argentina, Iceland) I've had to send my bags through a bigger (more powerful ?) X-Ray machine after immigration before leaving the airport.

Does Istanbul have such a setup ?

*Note: This isn't a question about photography, please don't tell me about ISO, or that film is or isn't affected by X-Rays and checked vs carry-on*

Comment: @JoErNano we have airport tags *and* city tags ? cool !

Comment: Yup. It's better to use airport tags when the question is airport-specific. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The last time I went to IST there was no xray customs inspection on the way out of the airport (if there was one I was not selected to go through it), but there is one on the way in at the airport entrance before the check in desk and a second xray scan at the real security check point.

Information from July 2014

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Istanbul too have the same kind of system, For your kind information Istanbul have reestablished the new security system, I would like to mention here one news article posted in 2007 regarding Istanbul security system, in [TODAYS ZAMAN](http://www.todayszaman.com/national_new-security-system-at-istanbul-airport-relieves-passenger-traffic_103348.html), They have installed explosives detection system (EDS), the EDS provided luggage security in stages. The system has both X-ray and tomography devices.
Feel free to ask any other queries you have or you want to know more about it
Thank-You!

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if the machines are modern or of older design ?

Comment: Sorry right now I don't have any data regarding the machine design type but usually security machines are kept same until the new system have the capacity to identify more threats as compared to previous one, It was reestablished in 2007 and now its been 7-8 years, So it might be updated and being change to modern.